# How to read appsettings.json file using webpack.config or tsconfig.json in .net-core react redux project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, .net-core, appsettings

1. I am setting up .net-core with a react-redux project in VS 2017. I removed default CleintApp and created a new folder with "npm create-react-app --typescript".

   - Here are multiple questions

     1. Where I can find webpack.config.json file
     2. How can I read appsettings.json file using webpack.config file to import third party library URL which is set in appsettings.json

```
appsettings.json
  {
    "menuUrl": "",
    "apiUrl": "",
  }
```

Now I want to read menuURL and import in webpack?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
const appsettings = require('./appsettings.json');
```

Then use it as follows:

```
appsettings.menuUrl;
```

Example

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const appsettings = require('./appsettings.json');

module.exports = env => {

    var version = appsettings.AppSettings.AppVersion;
    var lastIndex = version.lastIndexOf(".");
    var majorMinorVersion = version.substring(0, lastIndex);

...
    return {
        entry: {
            app: './ElmMobile/index.js'
        },

...
```

Comment: Where should we add above code, I mean which file? do you have any example

Comment: Added an example @Mahesh